# What would actually come out of Heisenberg's cat's box?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Maybe better asked: If you found a Heisenberg box lying around what would you expect to be in it? Suppose an H-box-like structure had been around since the big bang, what would be in it? Would opening a H-box be kindasorta equivalent to opening a wormhole to somewhere outside your light cone?

I feel like I've a decent enough lay-understanding of the uncertainty principle but if my understanding isn't way out of wack it seems like the box should be the remarkable, maybe horrifying thing about the cat thought experiment. I'm sorry this question rambles, it's been bugging me. If I'm way off base let me know.

If I'm right it has to not be just that I'm not observing the state of a machine in the box, rather that no information about the contents of the box is available at all. While the box is closed I couldn't build an amazing new telescope to watch in a few hours how Jupiter's atmosphere was affected by neutrinos that passed through the cat. "Observation" of the cat is any quantum coherence or entanglement or what-have-you between the cat and the universe I can detect. Right?

What's the difference between an H-box and an event horizon? If you had a macro-scale particle isolator it's a reasonable hunch that if you put a few kg of cat in and closed the door the contents would still behave like a few kg of cat but would that have to be the case? When you opened the door and the outermost particles start entangling with the rest of the universe why would they think they're supposed to respond cat-shapedly? A nitrogen molecule wouldn't enter the box looking for cats. A quantum of energy in the box, if it had to guess, would probably not guess that it was a cat particle. What would keep the entropy of the contents of the box in the cat realm, why wouldn't you find a bunch of warm gas or a blip of neutronium? What would keep the particles in the box interacting with one another, from our perspective?

Comment: Still better said: Would a Heisenberg box, if it was a well-defined concept that could be created, not be a bizarre, horrible machine?

Comment: Hi ynaq. I think your question seems impossible to understand in its current form because you likely have too many misunderstandings all at once. If you really want your questions answered, I'd stick to asking one thing at a time, (and doing more research on your own), before asking the question.

Comment: Yes. Ask one question at a time, so that you have a bit of a footing when you ask the next question. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

#### Either a dead cat or a living cat.

Schrodinger's cat thought experiment proposed putting a cat in a box with a mechanism that would kill the cat based on whether or not a particular atom had undergone radioactive decay. As a result, when you opened the box, there would be a 50% chance that the cat would be alive, and a 50% chance that the cat would be dead.

So, the answer to your question about what you would find inside it when you open it is simple: it contains either a dead cat or a living cat.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose an H-box-like structure had been around since the big bang, what would be in it?

I assume by “H-box” you mean a box originally containing a cat, as in Schrodinger’s cat thought experiment.

The box would contain hydrogen, carbon, oxygen and nitrogen atoms and some trace elements. Possibly some simple molecules. Certainly nothing resembling a cat. Time still passes within the box, and the second law of thermodynamics still applies to its contents.